# Netbeans login form using JFRAME

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to show a login page in netbeans using Jframe . So i have done a login form in that. but i want to cancel the maximize button which showing in the run time upper  side between of the minimize and closing button (in all windows page). is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways that you can approach this.

a) make the JFrame not resizable. This will not remove the maximize button but instead it will disable it.

```
    JFrame theFrame = new JFrame();
    theFrame.setSize(300,300);
    theFrame.setResizable(false);
    theFrame.setVisible(true);
```

b) Use a JDialog instead.

Hope this answers your question